# Best web hosting for photo blog sites with several photos and month visitors

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, shared-hosting, looking-for-hosting

What hosting provider would you recommend for photo blog sites with large / several photos upload as well as large traffic?

The hosting must be able to:

- accommodate 10,000 - 50,000 monthly visitors
- have unlimited domains
- have unlimited sub-domains
- have unlimited email address
- host large amount of images (thousands - millions, thinking long in term) since it will be a photo blog
- cPanel (not required but will be better if it has since I'm not really too techie with setting up the server from ground zero)
- PHP and MYSQL
- $10 budget monthly

Comment: "thinking long in term" - you don't need to think too "long term" providing you can buy more resources when needed. (50K monthly visitors and millions of images for $10 a month?)

Comment: are there hosting providers that could give those requirements (or aleast) in an affordable price? Upgrade is a no problem for me in case I exceed the hosting's limit. Heard above Amazon web services but I'm not sure if they could host media files only for my web app to just direct link to it. Also their pricing is vague. How do they really charge customers? I can see no price list on their site.